# Finding degree of extension of splitting field of a polynomial

Tags: splitting-field

> Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)=x^{3}+πx+6$ over $F =\mathbb{Q}(π)$ and $K'$ be the splitting field of $g(x)=x^{3}+ex+6$ over $F'=\mathbb{Q}(e)$.
>
> Is $[K:F]=[K':F']$ ?

$f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(π)$ and it has only one real root and two complex roots. So $[K:F]=6$ (as degree of extension of splitting field divides $n!$, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial). Similarly $[K':F']=6$.
Is this  correct?